# Server.HandleClient() alternative for AsyncWebServer with ESP32

Tags: c++, webserver, esp32

As a personal challenge I've been learning C++ and ESP32. Now, I´ve been trying to make a webserver with the next features:

1. Switch;
2. Dimmer;
3. Another switch with Timer;
4. Show Sensor measurements;
5. "Over The Air" Functionality;

While using `AsyncWebServer server(80)` I cannot use `server.handleClient()` and I'm Honestly lost.

Is it better to do another code?

Can I make my own library with both AsyncWebServer and WebServer (that has the handleclient() object method)?

The code is shown next:

````
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncEventSource.h>
#include <Ticker.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "MOVISTAR_9C70";
const char* password = "z4j7EuF9CWRnsmwhWJLT";
const int switchPin = 4;
const int dimmerPin = 5;
const int timerPin = 6;
const int sensorPin = A0;
const int timerInterval = 5000;  // Intervalo de tiempo para activar/desactivar el interruptor con temporizador en milisegundos

AsyncWebServer server(80);
bool switchState = false;
int dimmerValue = 0;
bool timerSwitchState = false;
Ticker timer;

void handleRoot(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  String html = "<html><body>";
  html += "<h1>Control de características con ESP32</h1>";

  // Switch
  html += "<h2>Switch</h2>";
  html += "<label>Estado: <input type=\"checkbox\" onchange=\"sendRequest('/toggle', this.checked)\" " + String(switchState ? "checked" : "") + "></label>";

  // Dimmer
  html += "<h2>Dimmer</h2>";
  html += "<input type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"255\" value=\"" + String(dimmerValue) + "\" onchange=\"sendRequest('/dimmer?value=' + this.value)\">";

  // Timer Switch
  html += "<h2>Otro Switch con Timer</h2>";
  html += "<label>Estado: <input type=\"checkbox\" onchange=\"sendRequest('/timerToggle', this.checked)\" " + String(timerSwitchState ? "checked" : "") + "></label>";

  // Sensor Measurements
  html += "<h2>Mediciones de Sensor</h2>";
  html += "<p>Valor: <span id=\"sensorValue\"></span></p>";
  html += "<script>setInterval(function() {";
  html += "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();";
  html += "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {";
  html += "  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {";
  html += "    document.getElementById('sensorValue').textContent = xhr.responseText;";
  html += "  }";
  html += "};";
  html += "xhr.open('GET', '/sensor', true);";
  html += "xhr.send();";
  html += "}, " + String(timerInterval) + ");</script>";

  html += "</body></html>";
  request->send(200, "text/html", html);
}

void handleToggle(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  String state = request->arg("state");

  if (state == "true") {
    switchState = true;
    digitalWrite(switchPin, HIGH);
  } else if (state == "false") {
    switchState = false;
    digitalWrite(switchPin, LOW);
  }

  request->send(200, "text/plain", "Estado del switch: " + state);
}

void handleDimmer(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  String value = request->arg("value");
  dimmerValue = value.toInt();
  analogWrite(dimmerPin, dimmerValue);

  request->send(200, "text/plain", "Valor del dimmer: " + value);
}

void handleTimerToggle(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  String state = request->arg("state");

  if (state == "true") {
    timerSwitchState = true;
    // Activar el temporizador y configurar la función de activación/desactivación del interruptor con temporizador
    timer.attach_ms(timerInterval, []() {
      digitalWrite(timerPin, !digitalRead(timerPin));
    });
  } else if (state == "false") {
    timerSwitchState = false;
    // Desactivar el temporizador y apagar el interruptor con temporizador
    timer.detach();
    digitalWrite(timerPin, LOW);
  }

  request->send(200, "text/plain", "Estado del interruptor con temporizador: " + state);
}

void handleSensor(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  request->send(200, "text/plain", String(sensorValue));
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(switchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dimmerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(timerPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(switchPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dimmerPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(timerPin, LOW);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Conectando a Wi-Fi...");
  }
   Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Configurar actualización por aire (OTA)
  ArduinoOTA.begin();

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);
  server.on("/toggle", HTTP_GET, handleToggle);
  server.on("/dimmer", HTTP_GET, handleDimmer);
  server.on("/timerToggle", HTTP_GET, handleTimerToggle);
  server.on("/sensor", HTTP_GET, handleSensor);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Servidor iniciado!");
  Serial.print("Dirección IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
//aqui solo lo dejé como comment e investigar si algo ocurre
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
}```



While building, the error message was that: Error: 'class AsyncWebServer' has no member named 'HandleClient'.
````

Answer (score 0):

Once the server is started with server.begin(), it will automatically handle incoming client requests in the background. You don't need to explicitly call a handleClient() function. (just delete the line of code)